# Getting error message as SQLException: No suitable driver found for url

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, jdbc

Im new to postgresql db. I have to create a login page, i have already stored some username and password in a table.Jar files are already added in the classpath.
Here is the servlet code

```
try
        {
            url2 = getServletContext().getInitParameter("url");
            driver = getServletContext().getInitParameter("name");
            username = getServletContext().getInitParameter("username");
            password = getServletContext().getInitParameter("password");
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();

            Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("url","username","password");

            PreparedStatement preparestatement=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM STORESETUPLOGIN WHERE username=? password=?");        
              preparestatement.setString(1,username);
               preparestatement.setString(2,password);
              ResultSet resultset=preparestatement.executeQuery();         
              status=resultset.next();
             if(status==true) {
                 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile.jsp");
                 rd.forward(request,response);
             }
             else{
                 out.print("Oops!!!Sorry username or password error");  
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");  
                    rd.include(request,response);
             }
        }catch(SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should not create connections manually like that. Configure and use a connection pool (`DataSource`) inside your servlet container.

Comment: Given the error message I'd say your connection URL is wrong - but you did not show us what URL you use, so it's impossible to answer.

Comment: just change url to url2 inside DriverManager.getConnection() because you are passing hardcoded url thats why it showing an error

Comment: I have been new to this database, but i have used only oracle database, so i dont know about using connection pool inside servlet container.

Comment: even after changing url to url2 still getting error

Comment: show updated code, you also have to remove double cotes " " from url or url2

Comment: Your code is using the literal string `"url"` to connect, so of course it won't work. That is not a valid JDBC url.

Comment: a simple java class with a main function is working perfectly. But while trying to connect with a servlet its showing the error.

Comment: Even with Oracle you should have used a connection pool

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `DriverManager.getConnection` with plain String literals as parameters

```
    Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("url","username","password");
```

You should use the String variables that you declare in the beginning of your code sample

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url2, username, password);
```